# Slick2D test application resulting in UnsatisfiedLinkException: wrong ELFCLASS

Tags: java, eclipse, opengl, lwjgl, slick2d

I'm writing a java-based game, trying to use Slick2D. However, when I try running the test application (below), I get this:

```
OpenJDK Server VM warning: You have loaded library /home/andrzej/Programming/Java/HeroesOfZether/lib/lwjgl/native/linux/liblwjgl.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/andrzej/Programming/Java/HeroesOfZether/lib/lwjgl/native/linux/liblwjgl.so: /home/andrzej/Programming/Java/HeroesOfZether/lib/lwjgl/native/linux/liblwjgl.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 (Possible cause: architecture word width mismatch)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1965)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1890)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1880)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:72)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:96)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:117)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:135)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer$1.run(AppGameContainer.java:39)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.<clinit>(AppGameContainer.java:36)
    at simpleslickgame.SimpleSlickGame.main(SimpleSlickGame.java:34)
```

I have done exactly like [the tutorial on Slick2D](http://slick.ninjacave.com/wiki/index.php?title=Setting_up_Slick2D_with_Eclipse) said, downloaded and unpacked slick and lwjgl archives, created a User Library, added run VM argument referencing the folder with natives (liblwjgl.so, liblwjgl32.so, libopenal.so, libopenal32.so), as you can see JVM finds them no problem, but then it encounters an architecture conflict. I am running Eclipse on 32-bit Linux Mint, with JDK and all properly installed and configured, I made a few small applications before without problem. There are no separate 32bit download options available on LWJGL site, and removing both the libraries without "32" in their name results back in UnsatisfiedLinkException: no lwjgl in java.library.path. This is the test application code:

```
package simpleslickgame;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.BasicGame;
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;

public class SimpleSlickGame extends BasicGame
{
    public SimpleSlickGame(String gamename)
    {
        super(gamename);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(GameContainer gc) throws SlickException {}

    @Override
    public void update(GameContainer gc, int i) throws SlickException {}

    @Override
    public void render(GameContainer gc, Graphics g) throws SlickException
    {
        g.drawString("Howdy!", 10, 10);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            AppGameContainer appgc;
            appgc = new AppGameContainer(new SimpleSlickGame("Simple Slick Game"));
            appgc.setDisplayMode(640, 480, false);
            appgc.start();
        }
        catch (SlickException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(SimpleSlickGame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This `wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 (Possible cause: architecture word width mismatch)` means that you are trying to run a 64bit LWJGL in a 32bit JVM.

You will have to switch to a 64bit JVM or if you already installed on you can set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to enable Linux to find the correct libraries. See [here]

If you are on a 32bit machine you will have to switch to a 32bit LWJGL.

Further reference: [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100751/minecraft-in-jdk-1-7-0-u2-x64); [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/502728/libomniorb4-so-1-wrong-elf-class-elfclass64)

Comment: The problem is, I have no idea how. There is no separate 32bit download on the site, like I said leaving only the libraries with "32" in their name just causes unsatisfied link error, and leaving and renaming them also produces an error.

Comment: Have you tried downloading the newest LWJGL and following [this guide](http://slick.ninjacave.com/wiki/index.php?title=Loading_libraries_and_natives_from_path) to get SLICK to use them? What bit-wise version of the JDK are you using?

Comment: According to [this](https://bitbucket.org/kevglass/slick/commits/all) the project is quite dead (sorry) , but you might find a fork that is still in development.

Comment: I searched for a bit, and the Slick forums seem to be active, and there is a "slick2d-maven" repository also not neglected, so it seems the specific 2D project I'm looking for is still supported. Also, thanks for the guide, but it just made everything even more complicated, because now I have FOUR different guides, all more or less official, each one describing other steps to take, other things to do, one says to get natives from lwjgl package, the other says from Slick package... Gonna look at that when it's not 4am, but I doubt much will change in the daylight.

Comment: After switching to everything from slick package (as it provides all the mentioned files) and completely ignoring the lwjgl one, finally something happened. By that I mean, it waited for a second, and then threw at me an UnsatisfiedLinkException: can't load liblwjgl.so, at the path I just checked it really is. I give up for today.